# Package hyperref Warning: Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding, removing `\textGamma' on input line 23

Tags: hyperref

I am writing lecture notes for ordinary differential equations in greek using the book class in Overleaf. Everything was fine (no errors, no warnings) till I included a png picture. Since I included the picture (named  1.png) every letter in chapter's title is giving a warning. I removed a lot of things from the code so that it doesn't get too long.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\title{Συνήθεις Διαφορικές Εξισώσεις}
 \author{}
 \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examp}{Παράδειγμα}[section]
 \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[examp]{Ορισμός}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{notice}[examp]{Παρατήρηση}
 \begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
  
\chapter{Γραμμικές ή ντετερμινιστικές εξισώσεις }






\includegraphics[width=5.5cm, height=4cm]{1}
```

The warning I get for the first letter`Package hyperref Warning: Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding, removing`\textGamma' on input line 23.`

Comment: You get warnings not errors. And this is unrelated to graphics: As David wrote, your tex-system/hyperref is probably older and so you need the option `unicode`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I looked for the version and it says Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020). What version should I use?

Comment: relevant is the hyperref version. With version hyperref 2021-02-27 v7.00k unicode is already the default, the current version is  7.00m

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it possible to load the newest package in Overleaf or I must use for example texmaker ?

Comment: overleaf will update to texlive 2021 in the near future. Until then using the unicode option mentioned by David should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should run without error with a current hyperref but otherwise use

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

so bookmarks can use Unicode rather than the original PDF string encoding (which does not allow Greek).